# get Attribute to insert it in my src ??, I do not know too much help me

Tags: javascript, src

The result that I get "undefined":

code js:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm"+x+".gif";
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("data");
```

HTML:

```
<img data="WhatIWantToAdd" id="myImg" src="" >
```

Comment: Maybe cause you use `x` before you define `x` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering was wrong. Even though x is declared, it's values is used before assignment. Hence the undefined

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("data");
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm"+x+".gif";
```

```html
<img data="WhatIWantToAdd" id="myImg" src="" >
```